# Android - Invoking activity with singletask again results black screen on android l

Tags: android

I have a `MainAcitvity(Singletask)`, a `SecondActivity`, and a `ForwardActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is `SecondActivity`:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_task_acitvity);
        findViewById(R.id.bt).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ForwardActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is `ForwardActivity`:

```
public class ForwardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forward);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ForwardActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

On android 5.0+, this causes black screen.

If I add SecondAcitvity with windowIsTranslucent, the problem of black screen dismiss.

How to solve the problem of black screen under not add windowIsTranslucent?

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: start activity with result and then use onActivityOnResult

Comment: thank you,but invoking MainActivity(Singletask)again means other activity be killed, thus causing the problem of black screen

Comment: is `SecondActivity ` inner class of `First Activity`?

Comment: sorry, SecondActivity is not inner class of First Activity.I missed a “}”